Unclear condition of the GPLv3 Interface Exception
I looked more closely at this FAQ entry on GPL 3.0 Interface Exception and I am a bit confused with the bolded text.
The goal of this exception is to be able to link independent modules, licensed under other licenses (including proprietary licenses), that use the ABCDEF interface of the ABC library which is licensed under GPLv3.
It says that the system (ABC + "other code") may be distributed under the terms of the GPL for ABC and the licenses of the "other code", provided that two conditions are met. One condition is that the ABCDEF interface is not modified. The other condition confuses me.
Why does the bolded text require that the source code of the "other code" be included, when the "other code" could be proprietary software?
Could it have been mistakenly worded and was actually intended to say "provided that you include the source code of ABC when and as the GNU GPL requires distribution of source code"?

As a special exception, the copyright holders of ABC give you
permission to combine ABC program with free software programs or
libraries that are released under the GNU LGPL and with independent
modules that communicate with ABC solely through the ABCDEF interface.
You may copy and distribute such a system following the terms of the
GNU GPL for ABC and the licenses of the other code concerned, provided
that you include the source code of that other code when and as the
GNU GPL requires distribution of source code and provided that you do
not modify the ABCDEF interface.


Contact your lawyer or the FSF or the FSFE since details are country specific. (I am French)

I'm pretty sure it just means "if the other code is under the GPL, then you can't use this exception as a get-out-of-GPL-obligations-free card for that other code." But I would like to see the FSF clarify this.

The only person who can definitively state why the exception still requires the distribution of source code is the person who wrote the exception.
Looking at the rest of the FAQ entry, it also states:

This exception enables linking with differently licensed modules over the specified interface (“ABCDEF”), while ensuring that users would still receive source code as they normally would under the GPL.

That is a clear indication to me that the exception is not mistakenly worded, but actually is worded as intended.
As there is no restriction on the licenses that those other components can have, this requirement seems to be aimed at at least giving you the right to study the software, even if you are not allowed to do anything else with the source code.
Note that this exception does not even have the requirement that you must be allowed to rebuild the application with a modified version of the GPL code.

I'm sorry I can't split the bounty, as both answers are excellent, and either in isolation would have deserved the bounty.  But I have to pick one, and apsillers' is longer, and better-referenced.

This exception appears to be heavily based on FreeRTOS's exception to the GPLv2, which dates back to at least 2006. The purpose of this exception was to allow non-GPL applications to use operating system interfaces for the GPLv2 FreeRTOS without incurring GPL obligations.
Interestingly, the text you emphasize in your question does not appear in FreeRTOS's original exception, but what it says instead may highlight the intent (emphasis mine):

As a special exception, the copyright holder of FreeRTOS gives you permission to link FreeRTOS with independent modules that communicate with FreeRTOS solely through the FreeRTOS API interface, regardless of the license terms of these independent modules, and to copy and distribute the resulting combined work under terms of your choice, provided that



Every copy of the combined work is accompanied by a written statement that details to the recipient the version of FreeRTOS used and an offer by yourself to provide the FreeRTOS source code should the recipient request it.
The combined work is not itself an RTOS, scheduler, kernel or related product.
The combined work is not itself a library intended for linking into other software applications.



Any FreeRTOS source code, whether modified or in it's original release form, or whether in whole or in part, can only be distributed by you under the terms of the GNU General Public License plus this exception. An independent module is a module which is not derived from or based on FreeRTOS.

Clearly, the final paragraph wishes to make it very clear that you cannot simply put GPLv2 code from FreeRTOS into some kind of "proprietary module" that communicates with FreeRTOS via an unmodified interface and then rely on this exception to bless your un-GPL-ing of that code. The mere fact that the GPL code appears in a context where this exception admits proprietary code does not remove the GPL obligations. The third bullet point also seeks to halt use of such a proprietary module as a linking access point for other software.
In view of this original language, it is highly suggestive to me that the FSF's revised language is likewise meant to stifle any funny business that attempts to use this exception as an avenue to distribute other people's GPL'd code under proprietary terms merely because the GPL'd code is included within (or links by further hops to) a proprietary module whose linkage with GPL code is allowed by this exception.
